# How do I force mysql to update when the only change is the case

Tags: mysql

I am changing the case of the data in a table to "title case". Since mysql does not have a function for title case, I am doing it in php.

however, if the data for id = 1 is "MR. JOHN ADAMS" then

Update contacts SET c_name = "Mr. John Adams" WHERE id = 1;

does nothing since MySql, being case insensitive, thinks nothing has changed.

I can't change mysql to be case sensitive in this installation.

Comment: what is the problem when executing the update statement? do you want a case senstitive search without changing any collation?

Comment: the update runs successfully, but it does not change anything when the only change is the "case". There is no search  I am supplying the ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested that in my MySQL and it works, it changes the case on the update. However, if it doesn't work for you, try this:

```
update contacts set c_name = binary 'John Adams' where id = 1
```

...and it should work.

Also try modifying your columnn definition from varchar(n) to varbinary(n), it may save you from having to specify binary on each insert/update.

HTH

Francisco

Comment: thanks it works, I had a stupid error. so it worked all along.